# Voting bar in javaFX 8

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8, rectangles

I have a Question how can i create this in Java with live update percentage

```
<div class="meter">
    <span id="bar1" style="width: 50%">test</span> 
    <span id="bar2" style="width: 50%">test</span>
</div>
```

You can see its a Bar (meter) lets say 1000px and two bars in it. If someone Vote for Team one bar1 is 100% and bar2 0% so in meter there is only bar1.

I try it with JavaFX 8 Rectangle that chang dynamicly width, but donst work becuase it dosnt update.

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jibble.pircbot.IrcException;
import org.jibble.pircbot.NickAlreadyInUseException;

import application.TwitchBot.Test;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;


public class Main extends Application implements Test{
     //local interface stuff
    TextArea output = new TextArea();
    Rectangle bar1 = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle bar2 = new Rectangle();

    double MID = 315;

    Stage secondStage = new Stage();        
    Pane BarPane = new Pane();
    Scene Bar = new Scene(BarPane, 650, 150, Color.GREEN);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws NickAlreadyInUseException, IOException, IrcException {

        //Stage 1
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        output.setEditable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(output);
        output.appendText("/// WELCOME TO THE TWITCH BOT PREALPHA ///");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Twitch Bot");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        //create Stage2


        BarPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00FF00");
        BarPane.setPrefSize(200,200);


        //BAR 1
        Rectangle bar1 = new Rectangle();
        bar1.setX(10);
        bar1.setY(50);
        bar1.setWidth(MID);
        bar1.setHeight(50);
        bar1.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        //Bar 2
        Rectangle bar2 = new Rectangle();
        bar2.setX(MID);
        bar2.setY(50);
        bar2.setWidth(650-MID-10);
        bar2.setHeight(50);
        bar2.setFill(Color.RED);

        BarPane.getChildren().addAll(bar1,bar2);

        secondStage.setTitle("Second Stage");
        secondStage.setScene(Bar); 
        secondStage.show(); 


        //Start BOT
        TwitchBot bot = new TwitchBot();
        bot.interfaceCallback = this;
        bot.setVerbose(true);
        bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:XXXXXXX");
        bot.joinChannel("#XXXXXXX");

    }
    public void stop(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void printScreen(String message) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                output.appendText("\n");
                output.appendText(message); 
                secondStage.show(); 
            }

        }); 
    }
    @Override
    public void setPercent(double Team1, double Team2) {
        MID = ((650*Team1)/100)-10;
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(MID);
                bar1.setWidth(MID);
                bar2.setX(MID);
                bar2.setWidth(650-MID-10);
            }
        }); 

    }
    @Override
    public void setTeamnames(String Team1, String Team2) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }); 

    }
}
```

TwitchBot.java

```
    package application;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class TwitchBot extends PircBot {

    // Count Votes
    double VoteT1 = 0;
    double VoteT2 = 0;
    double TotalVotes = 0;
    double T1percent = 0;
    double T2percent = 0;

    // User Arry (Every user can vote 1 time
    String users[] = new String[0];

    // Files
    File configFile = new File("config.properties");
    String team1 = "team1.txt";
    String team2 = "team2.txt";
    String teamnames = "teams.txt";

    // Write Channel
    String Channel = "#XXXXX";

    // Name
    String BotName = "DotaLanBot";

    // Default Keywords
    String Voting = "!voteing"; //Vote Statistics

    // Default Properties
    String Team1 = "none";
    String Team2 = "none";
    String Power = "XXX";

    public Test interfaceCallback;

    public interface Test{
        public void printScreen(String message);
        public void setPercent(double Team1, double Team2);
        public void setTeamnames(String Team1, String Team2);
    }

    public TwitchBot() {
        loadSettings();

        this.setName("dotalanbot");
        sendMessage(Channel, "Hi I'm your Bot");
        //writeInfile(teamnames, Team1 + "  vs  " + Team2);
        T1percent = 50;
        T2percent = 50;
    }

    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login,String hostname, String message) {
        //Chat ausgabe in Textfeld
        interfaceCallback.printScreen(sender+": "+message);


        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!win " + Team1)) {
            if (check(sender)) {
                System.out.println("vote team1");
                System.out.println(sender);
                VoteT1++;
                TotalVotes++;
                sendMessage(Channel, "Vote for " + Team1);
                T1percent = calcPercent(VoteT1);
                T2percent = calcPercent(VoteT2);
                interfaceCallback.setPercent(T1percent,T2percent);
            //  users(sender);
            }
        }
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!win " + Team2)) {
            if (check(sender)) {
                System.out.println("vote team1");
                System.out.println(sender);
                VoteT2++;
                TotalVotes++;
                sendMessage(Channel, "Vote for " + Team2);
                T1percent = calcPercent(VoteT1);
                T2percent = calcPercent(VoteT2);
                interfaceCallback.setPercent(T1percent,T2percent);
                //users(sender);
            }
        }
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(Voting)) {
            System.out.println(Team1 + ":" + VoteT1 + " Votes");
            System.out.println(Team2 + ":" + VoteT2 + " Votes");
            System.out.println("Total Votes:" + TotalVotes);
            sendMessage(Channel, Team1 + ":" + VoteT1 + " Votes  ||  " + Team2
                    + ":" + VoteT2 + " Votes  ||  " + "Total Votes:"
                    + TotalVotes);
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!resetvote")) {
            if (sender.equalsIgnoreCase(Power)) {
                sendMessage(Channel, "Voteing Reset");
                resetvote();
            }
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!test")) {
                sendMessage(Channel, "Test");
        }

        if(message.length()>9){
        if ((message.substring(0, 9)).equalsIgnoreCase("!setteam1" )) {
            if (sender.equalsIgnoreCase(Power)) {
                sendMessage(Channel, "Team 1 set to = "+message.substring(10));
                Team1 = message.substring(10);
            }
        }

        if ((message.substring(0, 9)).equalsIgnoreCase("!setteam2" )) {
            if (sender.equalsIgnoreCase(Power)) {
                sendMessage(Channel, "Team 2 set to = "+message.substring(10));
                Team2 = message.substring(10);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    //reset Voteing
    private void resetvote(){
        //writeInfile(teamnames, Team1 + "  vs  " + Team2);
        T1percent = 50;
        T2percent = 50;
        interfaceCallback.setPercent(T1percent,T2percent);
        String users[] = new String[0];
        saveSettings();
    }

    // write user to array
    private void users(String user) {
        String[] temp = new String[users.length + 1];
        temp[temp.length - 1] = user;
        users = temp;
    }

    // Check if user votes before
    private boolean check(String user) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(users[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // CALS PERCENT
    private double calcPercent(double calc) {
        double result = (calc / TotalVotes) * 100;
        return result;
    }

    // SETTINGS STUFF
    private void saveSettings() {
        // wirte Prop
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("Team1", Team1);
            props.setProperty("Team2", Team2);
            props.setProperty("Power", Power);

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configFile);
            props.store(writer, "settings");
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
        }
    }

    private void loadSettings() {
        // Read
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(reader);

            Team1 = props.getProperty("Team1");
            Team2 = props.getProperty("Team2");
            Power = props.getProperty("Power");

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O Error
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is BarPane? Where do you call setPercent? Why do you do a Platform.runLater there?

Comment: hey i dont want to offend anyone but ... i think you should learn programming and IT basics first. Maybe do a few beginners' tutorials and whatnot, JFX is a tad too complex for you right now - even *if* someone helps you you wont be able to create something useful nor will you learn much. We all need to start somewhere - and that somewhere definitely isnt to be found in advanced UI programming ... well at least not yet.

Comment: i attach full Code it works well, only thing is the UI dosnt update.

Comment: you managed to contradict yourself in one single sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rectangle`s you add to the scene graph (via `BarPane.getChildren().addAll(...)`) are not the same ones you reference outside the `start(...)` method. Hence when you update them in `setPercent(...)` with `bar1.setWidth(...)` and `bar2.setWidth(...)` you are not updating the `Rectangle`s that are displayed.

The problem is that you declare the instance variables a the beginning of the class definition with

```
Rectangle bar1 = new Rectangle();
Rectangle bar2 = new Rectangle();
```

and then in the `start(...)` method, you declare local variables with the same names:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // ...
    Rectangle bar1 = new Rectangle();
    // ...
    Rectangle bar2 = new Rectangle();
    // ...
}
```

Since you have declared them again here, they are not the same variables.

To fix this, just remove the declaration in the `start(...)` method, i.e.:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // ...
    bar1 = new Rectangle();
    // ...
    bar2 = new Rectangle();
    // ...
}
```

It is probably a good idea to remove the initialization at the top of the class too. That way if you did make the error you made, you would be notified as soon as you tried to access them, with a `NullPointerException`. So:

```
public class Main extends Application implements Test{

    //...

    Rectangle bar1 ;
    Rectangle bar2 ;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // ...

        bar1 = new Rectangle();
        // ...

        bar2 = new Rectangle();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok i will try it i think is a copy paste failure and i dont delet it in start methode.

Comment: THANKS it work, i just dont see that little mistake =/ Thanks a lot